# Division by zero exception issue

Tags: postgresql, coalesce, nullif

I am running this query where I calculate :

- the number of active users in the previous period
- the number of returning users (users active in the previous period and in the current period)
- retention rate ( returning_users/previous_period_active_user)

The problem is that 'previous_period_active_user' and 'returning_user' return the correct results, but the 'retention_rate' always returns zero.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I am aware of the division by zero error in PostgreSQL and that's why I am using COALESCE and NULLIF functions.

Query:

```
SELECT
    au.time_gran,
    au.time,
    au.country,
    count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active_1_period_before) AS previous_period_active_user,
    count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active AND au.active_1_period_before) AS returning_users,
    COALESCE(
        count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN au.active AND au.active_1_period_before THEN au.user_id END) /
        NULLIF(count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active_1_period_before), 0),
        0
    ) AS retention_rate
FROM active_users au
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use only integers in a division, you will get integer division.

`count()` return integer, so you will need to cast them to floats as part of the calculation (multiply by `1.0`) :

```
SELECT
    au.time_gran,
    au.time,
    au.country,
    count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active_1_period_before) AS previous_period_active_user,
    count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active AND au.active_1_period_before) AS returning_users,
    COALESCE(
        count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN au.active AND au.active_1_period_before THEN au.user_id END) * 1.0 /
        NULLIF(count(DISTINCT au.user_id) FILTER (WHERE au.active_1_period_before) * 1.0, 0),
        0
    ) AS retention_rate
FROM active_users au
group by au.time_gran, au.time, au.country
```

Comment: Minor point `count` in postgresql returns `bigint`.

Comment: Also interesting trick to multiply by 1.0 - the answer I was writing  before you posted used cast instead.  Is multiply by 1.0 faster/more efficient?

Comment: It's just quicker to type `* 1.0` :) .. not sure which one is faster